# Can't get Data from XML to LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have XML file quotes.xml. For my Windows Phone Project.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Motivation>
    <Quotes>
      <Quote Category ="Junk" Content='Alaa Alee Aluee'/>
      <Quote Category ="Junk" Content='Alee Aleu Alue'/>
      <Quote Category ="Junk" Content='Aluua Alue Aluee'/>
      <Quote Category ="Junk" Content='Blaa Alee Aluee'/>
      <Quote Category ="Jingalaga" Content='Bee Aleu Alue'/>
      <Quote Category ="Jingalaga" Content='Bluua Alue Aluee'/>
      <Quote Category ="Jingalaga" Content='Blaa Blee Bluee'/>
      <Quote Category ="Jingalaga" Content='Blee Bleu Blue'/>
      <Quote  Category ="Jingalaga" Content='Bluua Blue Bluee'/>
      <Quote  Category ="Jingalaga" Content='Claa Clee Cluee'/>
      <Quote  Category ="Jingalaga" Content='Clee Cleu Clue'/>
      <Quote  Category ="Jingalaga" Content='Cluua Clue Cluee'/>
    </Quotes>
    </Motivation>
```

I want to access the Content by Each Category User Selects. If I have Value "Junk" from User, I am not able to get proper data as I expect.

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load("Quotes.xml");
        var quot = from var in doc.Descendants("Quote")
                   where var.Attribute("Category").Value == "Junk"
                   select new Quote
                   { 
                     demo  = var.Attribute("Content").Value
                   };
        quot = quot.ToList();
        cat.Text = quot.First().ToString();
```

I'm getting out put as **Motivate.Quote**. What I expect is "Alaa Alee Aluee"
Also How can I be able to get random data as out put based on User click for more quote?

Comment: Thanks L.B, Also please could you provide a way to get Random quotes?

Comment: What problem did you have when using the Random class?

Comment: L.B How to use Random Class as per the requirement of my logic. Basically my app contains button, on click I need the present quote to be refreshed randomly from our xml file. Also Giving importance, that the list should not repeat unless the list is fully displayed once!

Comment: Well what have you tried? Have you looked at the API of the `Random` class? Which methods look most suitable? Between this request and the one on my answer, it sounds like you're expecting to be spoon-fed, and that's just not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're creating an instance of `Quote`, and not overridden `ToString` in your `Quote` class. Given that you're currently only pulling out the content anyway, I'd just create a `List<string>` instead:

```
var quotes = XDocument.Load("Quotes.xml")
                      .Descendants("Quote")
                      .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Category") == "Junk")
                      .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("Content"))
                      .ToList();

cat.Text = quotes.First();
```

If you *do* want to use a `Quote` class, then you should probably specify *all* the details when creating the quote, and give the properties meaningful names:

```
var quotes = XDocument.Load("Quotes.xml")
                      .Descendants("Quote")
                      .Select(x => new Quote {
                                 Content = (string) x.Attribute("Content"),
                                 Category = (string) x.Attribute("Category")
                              })
                      .Where(q => q.Category == "Junk")
                      .ToList();

cat.Text = quotes.First().Content;
```

Comment: It will be better if you explain me each line of code, as I am beginner in C# and LINQ

Comment: @SivaRajini: Please don't add comments asking for attention on unrelated questions.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin: No, I'm not going to explain every little bit of it. You try to work out what's going on, doing whatever research you can, and then you can ask about *specific* parts you don't understand.

Comment: dot operator gives me trouble, Visual Studio giving error. What mistake I did? The SOlution from @PeterFromCologne and L.B worked although

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin: Try now (there was a stray semi-colon at the end of the first line in each example) - but next time, don't just say "giving error" - you need to tell us what the error *is*.

Comment: Thanks Sir :).. Even my code works, when I add demo property which I actually forgot cat.Text = quot.First().demo.ToString()

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin: Yes, although you don't need the `ToString()` there. But `demo` is a fairly meaningless name here, and if you just need a string then there's little point in having a whole class to wrap it at all.

Comment: Note: in answer its == not != .. Thanks Jon Skeet :)

Answer (score 0):

You get a Quote object while you look for it's demo property:
cat.Text = quot.First().demo.ToString();

Will fix it.